# label visible still with ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So my mark up:

```
<div class="box" ng-show="clearNow">
  <div ng-repeat="items in product | limitTo: limit as prodItems">
   <span class="title">{{title}}</span>
    <div class="content" ng-include="'contentfiles.html'">main content here</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In my code:

```
var limit = 1;
$scope.clear=function(){
$scope.clearNow=!$scope.clearNow;
}
```

Two things, on load the items are not appearing as I have the ng-show="clear" which doesn't take into account my var limit, however when I click ng-click=clear I do get the right results.

Now more interestingly the second issue - when I do:

```
<a href ng-click="clear()">clear</a>
```

The items reset to be the limit, however this time the tag:

```
<span class="title">{{title}}</span>
```

I actually get through for the second item - however not the content, as that is removed correctly. I'm wondering how I can force the title to be removed too, as it wants to stay in the page!

Comment: change `ng-show='clear'` to `ng-show='clear()'`. Right now your `ng-show` is always evaluating truthy because `clear` (which is a function) is a truthy value.

Comment: apologies, it's a typo, I have it set to the scope and not the function, will edit the question

Comment: Can you do a repro on this in jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: Have you set clearNow to e.g. `false` before rest of the code?

Comment: no I didn't, that has solved the first on-load, so thank you for that :)